# Rango de horas en un TimeEditFor con DevExpress

Tags: asp.net-mvc, devexpress

Me encuentro haciendo un TimeEdit con devexpress y necesito que solo se puedan escoger determinados rangos, mi código es el siguiente:

```
itemEndDate.SetNestedContent(() => Html.DevExpress().TimeEditFor(model => model.EndTime, settings =>
                                         {
                                             settings.Name = "EndDate" + item.AvailabilityId;
                                             settings.Properties.ValidationSettings.RequiredField.IsRequired = true;
                                             settings.Properties.EditFormat = EditFormat.Time;
                                             settings.ShowModelErrors = true;
                                             settings.Properties.ClientInstanceName = "EndDate" + item.AvailabilityId;
                                         }).GetHtml());
```

busco ajustar un mínimo y un máximo de las horas escogidas por el usuario, alguien tiene una recomendación? gracias.

Answer (score 0):

El TimeEdit no proporciona este tipo de validaciones lamentablemente. El valor de tiempo se cicla dentro de las 24 horas. Te sugiero manejar el evento `TimeEdit.Validating` para comprobar los valores en función o usar ClientSideEvents para validar en JS.

Comment: Hola @Anahí gracias por tu aporte. Me parece que esta respuesta se podría beneficiar enormemente con más detalles. Es decir, ¿Cómo sería el código para manejar la validación en `TimeEdit.Validating`? ¿Cómo se comprobaría que entra dentro de un rango?... O, en su defecto, ¿cómo se haría desde JavaScript? La idea es sumar contenido con la mayor calidad posible al sitio. Como tal, se busca responder a preguntas de programación, en la mayoría de los casos, con código que responda y solucione el problema.